# Selenium RC locators - referring to subsequent elements?

Tags: selenium-rc

When there is more than a single element with the same locator in a page, how should the next elements be referenced?

Using Xpath locators it's possible to add array notation, e.g. xpath=(//span/div)[1]
But with simple locators?

For example, if there are 3 links identified by "link=Click Here", simply appending [3] won't get the 3rd element.

And where is the authoritative reference for addressing array of elements? I couldn't find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium doesn't handle arrays of locators by itself. It just returns the first element that meets your query, so if you want to do that, you have to use xpath, dom or even better, css.

So for the link example you should use:

```
selenium.click("css=a:contains('Click Here'):nth-child(3)")
```

Comment: thanks! i had no idea it's possible (and is much more readable than xpath)

Answer (score 0):

Santi is correct that Selenium returns the first element matching your specified locator and you have to apply the appropriate expression of the locator type you use. I thought it would be useful to give the details here, though, for in this case they do border on being "*gory details*":

### CSS

The `:nth-child` pseudo-class is tricky to use; it has subtleties that are little-known *and* not clearly documented, even on the W3C pages. Consider a list such as this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="bird">petrel</li>
  <li class="mammal">platypus</li>
  <li class="bird">albatross</li>
  <li class="bird">shearwater</li>
</ul>
```

Then the selector `css=li.bird:nth-child(3)` returns the **albatross** element not the **shearwater**! The reason for this is that it uses your index (3) into the list of elements that are siblings of the first matching element--*unfiltered by the .bird class*! Once it has the correct element, in this example the third one, it *then* applies the bird class filter: if the element in hand matches, it returns it. If it does not, it fails to match.

Now consider the selector `css=li.bird:nth-child(2)`. This starts with the second element--platypus--sees it is not a bird and comes up empty. This manifests as your code throwing a "not found" exception!

What might fit the typical mental model of finding an indexed entry is the CSS `:nth-of-type` pseudo-class which applies the filter *before* indexing. Unfortunately, this is not supported by Selenium, according to the official documentation on [locators](http://release.seleniumhq.org/selenium-core/1.0.1/reference.html#locators).

### XPath

Your question already showed that you know how to do this in XPath. Add an array reference at any point in the expression with square brackets. You could, for example use something like this: `//*[@id='abc']/div[3]/p[2]/span` to find a span in the second paragraph under the 3rd div under the specified id.

### DOM

DOM uses the same square bracket notation as XPath *except* that DOM indexes from zero while XPath indexes from 1: `document.getElementsByTagName("div")[1]` returns the second div, not the first div! DOM offers an alternate syntax as well: `document.getElementsByTagName("div").item(0)` is exactly equivalent. And note that with getElementsByTagName you *always* have to use an index since it returns a node set, not a single node.